# tmux - how to display an image in a pane?

Tags: python, asciimatics

I'd like to display an animated GIF or any other image in a pane in tmux.

I'm playing with [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics) to do this, and have modded one of the sample programs (images.py) to:

- display a single image
- show no error messages on "Ctrl+C"
- accept a single command line arg "image filename"

Here's the script I have and the only issue is that it seems to do a slow refresh of the image being displayed ~ every 10 seconds. How do I remove this refresh, since the image is a static image?

#### image.py

```
from __future__ import division
from asciimatics.effects import BannerText, Print, Scroll
from asciimatics.renderers import ColourImageFile, FigletText, ImageFile
from asciimatics.scene import Scene
from asciimatics.screen import Screen
from asciimatics.exceptions import ResizeScreenError
import sys

total = len(sys.argv)-1
if (total < 1):
    print ("Usage: IMG")
    sys.exit(1)

# Parsing args one by one
IMG = str(sys.argv[1])

def demo(screen):
    scenes = []
    effects = [
        Print(screen,
              ColourImageFile(
                  screen, IMG, 
                  screen.height-2,
                  uni=screen.unicode_aware,
                  dither=screen.unicode_aware),
                  0,
                  stop_frame=200
            )
    ]
    scenes.append(Scene(effects))
    screen.play(scenes, stop_on_resize=True)


# capture ctrl+c and exit nicely
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            Screen.wrapper(demo)
            #Screen.wrapper(demo, catch_interrupt=True)
            sys.exit(0)
        except ResizeScreenError:
            sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had to set `stop_frame=0` and it works as hoped, as specified [in the docs](https://asciimatics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/asciimatics.html)

#### Example usage

```
$ python image.py /images/fox.jpg
```

#### image.py

```
from __future__ import division
from asciimatics.effects import BannerText, Print, Scroll
from asciimatics.renderers import ColourImageFile, FigletText, ImageFile
from asciimatics.scene import Scene
from asciimatics.screen import Screen
from asciimatics.exceptions import ResizeScreenError
import sys

total = len(sys.argv)-1
if (total < 1):
    print ("Usage: IMG")
    sys.exit(1)

# Parsing args one by one
IMG = str(sys.argv[1])

def demo(screen):
    scenes = []
    effects = [
        Print(screen,
              ColourImageFile(
                  screen, IMG, 
                  screen.height-2,
                  uni=screen.unicode_aware,
                  dither=screen.unicode_aware),
                  0,
                  stop_frame=200
            )
    ]
    scenes.append(Scene(effects))
    screen.play(scenes, stop_on_resize=True)


# capture ctrl+c and exit nicely
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
        sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            Screen.wrapper(demo)
            #Screen.wrapper(demo, catch_interrupt=True)
            sys.exit(0)
        except ResizeScreenError:
            sys.exit(0)
```